# Why can’t I edit this post?

Tags: bug, editing

The following question has some formatting issues that I wanted to correct.

[Econometrics problem with regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/561879/247274)

I cannot edit it, even though I can edit other questions (not just my own).

What’s going on? All I can think is that I missed
a rule that only diamond mods can edit posts by brand new members.

**EDIT**

Once the question got closed, I could edit it.

Comment: Weird. On mobile, the post didn’t have an edit button, but it did on my laptop.

Comment: I am on my phone, but it was just that one question that lacked the edit button, and now it’s back. // Wait…even a diamond mod had a lack of edit ability?

Comment: I have a feeling that the user interface is doing more weird things recently and is continuously changing a bit, as if they are testing out some things.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be transient behavior, perhaps related to recent revisions to the SE layout. I haven't been able to reproduce it. I'm not aware of a rule (e.g. related to reputation, or moderator status) that would remove the edit button. If the issue persists & is reproducible, then posting to meta.SE is the best place, because it tracks bugs in SE software (diamond mods have no power over the SE software).

Comment: I couldn't edit a post yesterday for some unknown reason, and just gave up. I agree that's not much information, but it ties in with the general chatter here. (Clearly, I am not a moderator either.)